# why Bisecting k-means does not working in python?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

My code:

```py
from sklearn.cluster import BisectingKMeans
bisect_means = BisectingKMeans(n_clusters=2, n_init=10, max_iter=300, random_state=10).fit(pcdf)
```

Error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'BisectingKMeans' from 'sklearn.cluster' (C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\__init__.py)
```

Comment: It is new in version 1.1, maybe you are running on an older version ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be the case that you use an older version of the scikit-learn module. I had the same error. Upgraded it by running `pip install --upgrade scikit-learn`, it helped me.